# Check the sizes of members of a reactiveValues object

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to iterate over all of the items in a shiny::reactiveValues object and check their size in memory? As an example:

```
obj <- shiny::reactiveValues()
obj$a <- data.frame(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=1, max=10), nrow=50)))
obj$b <- data.frame(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=1, max=10), nrow=50)))
obj$c <- data.frame(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=1, max=10), nrow=50)))
```

I'd like to be able to (1) get all the names of the items in 'obj', and (2) get their sizes in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job. I changed the length of `obj$b` because otherwise you wouldn't be able to see that the objects are different sizes.

```
library(shiny)

  ui <- fluidPage(
      tableOutput('table')
      )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {

    obj <- shiny::reactiveValues()
    obj$a <- data.frame(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=1, max=10), nrow=50)))
    obj$b <- data.frame(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=1, max=10), nrow=500)))
    obj$c <- data.frame(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=1, max=10), nrow=50)))

    output$table <- renderTable({
      df <- data.frame()
      for (i in 1:length(names(obj))){
        name <- names(obj)[i]
        size <- as.numeric(utils::object.size(obj[[name]]))
        df <- rbind(df,data.frame(size,name))
      }
      df
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]